# Easy quick way to Migrate LAMP settings and Ubuntu Users from old Ubuntu 19.04 to new fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: server, 20.04, 19.04, lamp, migration

I have an old Ubuntu 19.04 server and I have many users and client sites here. I want to migrate everything to a fresh server install of Ubuntu 20.4. Is there an easy way to migrate the following:

- Users and their home directories (I just copied all the /home folders)
- Mysql databases
- PHP 7.2 settings -- I need to keep old php version
- Apache settings
- And anything else I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

- Home directories - copy `/home` folders, but remember to keep ownership & permissions (tar/untar should do the job)
- Users - copy lines with uids >= 1000 in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files. Also copy user groups in `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow`.
- Mysql databases - the canonical method is to make `mysqldump` of the old databases and import the dumps into the new instance. You may also need to copy MySQL settings, if there's something non-default there (`/etc/mysql` directory)
- PHP and Apache settings - copy `/etc/apache2` and `/etc/php` directories to the new server
- What else? Depends on what other services you run on the server, you need to copy settings for these  too.